# C#: Speech Synth with PromptBuilder not working right

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm of course guessing something is wrong with my computer, maybe a library somewhere.. not sure.
First off, at home, I can't get a male voice.  I figure this is because it has a different library at home, on Win7 Ultimate.  If anyone has any thoughts, I'd appreciate it.
On my work PC, winXP SP3 (.NET 4), I can get a male voice.... but...  pbuilder doesn't work right:

```
pbuilder.StartStyle(pStyle);
pbuilder.StartParagraph();
pbuilder.StartVoice(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Teen, 2);
pbuilder.StartSentence();
pbuilder.AppendText("Checking current weather.");
pbuilder.EndSentence();
pbuilder.EndVoice();
pbuilder.EndParagraph();
pbuilder.EndStyle();
ss.SpeakAsync(pbuilder);
```

Works at home... but at work, all it says (and I'm not joking) is "Blah".  If I put:

```
ss.SpeakAsync("Checking current weather");
```

Then it will say that.  ???

In case anyone is interested, I'm working on building my own... mini Jarvis (from Iron Man)
http://code.google.com/p/jarvisv2win7/

At the time of this writing, has speech recognition, will recognize given commands (Play Tchaikovsky....  Check email.. How cold is it?... etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a male voice on Windows 7 because there is no male voice installed on windows 7 by default.

XP has two English voices (Microsoft Sam and Microsoft Mary) installed by default, but 
Windows Vista and Windows 7 only have one English voice (Microsoft Anna) installed by default.
Therefore, on Windows 7, you won't be able to select a male voice because one is not installed.

According to the documentation for the [PromptBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.promptbuilder.startstyle%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class, Windows XP is not a supported platform.